# CSS - Element with 2 background images - How to drop shadow just around one of them?

Tags: css, background-image, shadow

I have a div element with two background images, both added using JavaScript.
The first background image, at the top of the div, is set according to "data-img" attribute, while the second one is always the same.

**HTML**

```
<div class="card" data-img="https://placehold.co/130x130"></div>
```

**JS**

```
document.querySelectorAll(".card").forEach(card => 
card.style.background = "url(" + card.dataset.img + ") no-repeat center top 20px, url(https://placehold.co/50x50) no-repeat center bottom 20px");
```

Is it possible - using "filter: drop-shadow", or in another way - to drop shadow just around the first image?

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".card").forEach(card => 
card.style.background = "url(" + card.dataset.img + ") no-repeat center top 20px, url(https://placehold.co/50x50) no-repeat center bottom 20px");
```

```css
.card {
border: 1px solid black;
height: 250px;
width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card" data-img="https://placehold.co/130x130"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a pseudo-element an inherit the background from the main element then make the size of the second one 0 and apply filter to it.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".card").forEach(card =>
  card.style.background = "url(" + card.dataset.img + ") no-repeat center top 20px, url(https://placehold.co/50x50) no-repeat center bottom 20px");
```

```css
.card {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 250px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
.card:before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background: inherit;
  background-size: auto,0 0;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px red);
}
```

```html
<div class="card" data-img="https://placehold.co/130x130"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a pseudo-element. Sadly, the support for `url(data-img, url)` is non-existant, but you can set a CSS variable on your element that points to your URL, and add that as the content for your pseudo-element. Then it's merely to add a box-shadow to your pseudo-element.

Bonus: no javascript required.

```css
.card {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 250px;
  width: 200px;
  background: url(https://placehold.co/50x50) no-repeat center bottom 20px;
}

.card::before {
  content: url(data-img, url); /* Proposed for future CSS, but doesn't work */
  content: var(--background);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px 0px #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="card" style="--background: url(https://placehold.co/130x130)"></div>
```